# Accessing owner window methods in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I basically want to access methods of owner window, but I get a Null Reference Exception

How does it look like now:
I have my MainWindow with public WriteLine method

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public void WriteLine(string text, params object[] args)
    {
        text = String.Format(text, args);
        outputBox.AppendText(text + "\r\n");
    }

    private void ShowPlot()
    {
        PlotWindow plotWindow = new PlotWindow();
        plotWindow.writeline += WriteLine;
        plotWindow.Owner = this;
        plotWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

Then in PlotWindow class I am trying to call WriteLine with these lines:

```
writeline("Drawing plot");
(Owner as MainWindow).WriteLine("Drawing plot");
```

As you can see, I'm calling it through Owner property and through using the delegate writeline in PlotWindow.
Any of these approaches gives me a System.NullReferenceException

What am I missing?

Comment: Where does the code that uses`Owner` reside? Is it in the constructor or a method?

Comment: It is in the method which is called in constructor after InitializeComponent()

Comment: I just put it outside of constructor and it works perfectly now, thank you very much.
But why? It was the last line of constructor, so I thought that there is no difference.

UPD Oh, I get it. I made a call from constructor right before setting window's Owner property and delegate. Now it looks too obvious, thank you again!

Comment: Added an answer with an explanation, hope it's clear enough:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you state in the comments, you invoke the `Owner` property from a method invoked by the constructor. This means you try to access values you have not set yet.

```
    PlotWindow plotWindow = new PlotWindow(); // This is where you try to access the Owner, this is where the constructor is invoked
    plotWindow.writeline += WriteLine;
    plotWindow.Owner = this; // This is where you set the owner
    plotWindow.Show();
```

Consider using an event that occurs after the window is shown, such as the Loaded event

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly it.
Thank you!